# how to run this timer in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, timer

I want a timer to run on a form whose value is derived from a database. for example when i store the value for the timer in a variable, i multiply it by 60000 to convert milliseconds to minutes. Here is the code:

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim x as integer
details = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Time") 
    Timer1.Interval =details * 60000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub()

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    seconds.Text = x.ToString
    If x= 0 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("You didn't finish in time.", "Sorry")
        Me.Close()
    Else
        x-= 1
    End If
End Sub
```

When i run this code, the timer runs in the background and when time's up, the form closes. But it doesn't show in the label seconds when timer is ticking. I hope you get what I mean :)

Comment: The tick only happens once every 60 seconds, hence the label gets updated once every 60 seconds in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the label to tick the seconds down to 0, you need the timer interval to be 1000, no matter how long you want this to run for.

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    details = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Time") 
    Timer1.Interval =1000
    endTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(details)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub()
Dim endTime As DateTime

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick       
    If DateTime.Now > endTime Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("You didn't finish in time.", "Sorry")
        Me.Close()
    Else
        Seconds.Text = (DateTime.Now - endTime).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you... it works as the seconds tick by. But then rather than the a big value of seconds ticking, how can I make it more user-friendly or rather look good

Comment: For simplicity sake, I'd recommend using a `Stopwatch` object to keep track of the total elapsed time.

Comment: @user3046786, To format the text differently, don't use `TotalSeconds.ToString`.  Use the `ToString` method of the `TimeSpan` object, which allows you to specify the format.  See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on `TimeSpan` formatting.

Comment: @user3046786 I updated the answer to use a better output format

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your timer ticks at `Minutes` interval. If you want to show seconds in the label then your timer should tick within 1 second interval (maybe a few milliseconds etc.)

So instead of setting `Timer1.Interval =details * 60000`, set `x = details * 60` and `Timer1.Interval` to  1000.

There is also `variable scoping` problem with your code. You have declared x as local variable inside `Form1_Load`, which means that it won't be available inside the `Timer1_Tick`. Move it outside the procedure.

```
Dim x As Integer

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Details = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Time")
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    x = Details * 60
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    seconds.Text = x.ToString
    If x = 0 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("You didn't finish in time.", "Sorry")
        Me.Close()
    Else
        x-= 1
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATED**

This is assuming that your database saved value is in Milliseconds. Otherwise modify appropriately.

```
Dim ticker As TimeSpan

Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Details = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Time")
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    ticker = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Details)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    seconds.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ticker.Hours, ticker.Minutes, ticker.Seconds)

    If ticker.Ticks <= 0 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("You didn't finish in time.", "Sorry")
        Me.Close()
    Else
        ticker = ticker.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The timer as he wrote it did _not_ tick at the minutes interval. It would tick exactly _once_, when time had run out.

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar : thank you... it works as the seconds tick by. But then rather than the a big value of seconds ticking, how can I make it more user-friendly or rather look good.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn : that was exactly what was happening

Comment: @user3046786: If you want you can convert the value of `x` to format HH:MM:SS in your `Timer1_Tick` event to show in label.

Comment: @PradeepKumar : sorry.. can you show me how to convert the value of x to HH:MM:SS

Comment: @PradeepKumar : thanks but it doesn't work. As soon as the form opens, message box pops up saying time's up

Comment: Just as I said, the code assumes that the value saved in database is in milliseconds. If it is in minutes or seconds, then use `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Details)` or `TimeSpan.Fromseconds(Details)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be completely what you may want, as I didn't convert the time or anything I just made it as basic as possiable and that way you should be able to work from it :)

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Time As Integer = 100 'Your time in seconds goes here!

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblTime.Text = Time
        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Time = Time - 1
    lblTime.Text = Time

    If Time = 0 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("You didn't finish in time.", "Sorry")
        Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any problems just message me